# How to extract string between selected string in python

Tags: python

if i have a string like:

```
str = 'Hello, <code>This is the string i want to extract</code>'
```

Then how will i extract string that are between `<code>` and `</code>`, In above case the extract string is:

```
'This is the string i want to extract'
```

I want to use this string in django filter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed. And downvoted.

Comment: I had not given any attempted solutions because i was no idea that how to do, as i am python learner i didn't learn Python Regular Expressions yet and did not know about BeautifulSoup. in my attempt i was just applying "for" and "if" loop, that does not comes close to real answer or what i really wanted to do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters who is this "Welcome to Stack..." snippet author and is it _CC BY_? I googled and it seems is most used by You, but not solely

Comment: @alko: Mine is based on text I found here on SO. The earliest reference I can find now is Nov. 7th last year, by me, I can no longer find the original text I based mine of.

Comment: @alko: Note that the "Welcome to Stack Overflow!" part is a nicety automatically added by the [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) script I use, for new-ish users on the site.

Comment: @alko: but the text is certainly CC BY, as I posted my version here on SO, where all user-contributed content is licensed as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parser such as `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> text = 'Hello, <code>This is the string i want to extract</code>'
>>> soup = BS(text)
>>> print soup.code.text
This is the string i want to extract
```

Or you can just use regex if it's just one line:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'<code>(.*?)</code>', text).group(1)
'This is the string i want to extract'
```

---

By the way, please don't name strings `str`. It will override the built-in type.

Comment: Great answer Haidro! :D +1 for both regex _and_ BS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , if you want "Hello" also

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
sentence = 'Hello, <code>This is the string i want to extract</code>'   
print re.sub('<[^>]*>', '',  sentence)

Hello, This is the string i want to extract
```